# How to render image from byteArray in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dio

I am getting some unusual data from the API, which I am not able to parse.

data looks something like.

```
�PNG
IHDR�9��A�  pHYs��~� IDATx��y�eWU��cε����껤�T�����H�Q:�D�rU@
�]xvHc���(��� v`0A�$�T���JU�R�i��k�9��c�s�*U    ����Ȭ���S{���\c�9��K��2�b�
�3�$�*˟��I�HԿq=9[Թ��Y�F���%��i����my?|��o߆H��1�#�^�yf�y5Ik���g��� Ni�B�߼�'��\~{G4;�sq.��m����sѷ��'_���>p+�V�����:����\��3h�Ą͘օ'��-\�������Mہ�ᑼ�Swr��l��[���5Ǎ���=_�V�c���{�|�
*4o�Oν���&�x˘����е�*$�m_�W�ʻ�P53�_��9c�����_�6��%�1p��o'�������ɗ\@���}�h����ǫ�_���_��ڵ��(�(*w*�0�(���$�H-��8Ќ2�A��(&���u�T�NB����pwN��k�{��]�ן='�ߩL�����'Y� �Y���Z���j�;�[>W\����w\�9'��{N]ś/����;�5�~���p+������dO�{�V�����8����894I:����0���P,:+�W��Ho8�<��'��/�t<��w�ox��ӷ������i��S�k���B�ý#��S�,`��~��fh����`j\�K�����ۮb��6��qŮ����g4
�
���着Mv��٠�ƕ��{#�9���_'�}�<����bR���ũɯ=�kĳ=�ɠ��W�
E)+-    �8`n�~��N�5GHX�h,l!����:ܝ+�Z�;?v���_��'��PX@qwDI�cNz���q1@�C��B0'���uD��@���.��3o��n�|�<XK2N@��%�<�_y�ƣn�I��Ώ�N�}�c~����Gl�]_��%����
'�$��}g3�a�]K��߼�,���|���@$�aD�
H���7�����Cз}���ƭ?������i
���E�e���h���]W�[W�������P�1o*t�    ��v������5�@:�u�z.>uO<e�Ǟ���ܝ��[ܔ�ȗ\���J��8h8u�F�����B�~ՏIi��$C
�q�2��*�"Ø騘��aӲ��m�(���y��0S9�KƤ�KBƱ,��3x`Q���������+_�P�]�P�HD�=ι��y*��I?y&�'�.~����CW��`L/yO���x�H�'��I��x�gw�8�����O�B�S4ER>��|�I��_�d��'��g�<Sx‰3Ԟy��v������<�=�\�+�](v�A^�Ww�nX����U��3�+{K��2|���W����Y[�o���3/ڂ�1�   �x�~ViƳ�-��c?{6?����d��g��0A�1:i���w������������\���Nb��s! ��}�mD   �*�>{5��ɰ=�?{�Z�@�H�������1�5"F�qB��Æ���s������|����v�'��~�g��P�\�X���[��A�f�ʩ���.��/M���҉ʰ^Xy9��s3��1��q�G�Ӝ�����K�����j�⩂���0?����m-�+��/��ӥ���ft�`�fSOx�]�7)_Lǹk���^ٸ�gDm�����Q>Ҭu��f���m|}�"�S����@pV��jZ   ؠ�W~��_��Rg,�����u���
�Ыo�-�_�q"�:�E�#$�-���_8�[�r?��=�6�~z�k�#�A�S�_�2���(3��D�2 ���)�s��g�A ����
�A��!,TFԽ�ʖY��}D�3���7<b=:1�k9e�[�����!o�|y0C�bEKL��Ё��kZ:�����
x��Onx�I+x���ɳ5"�]�5�������$���C�6�������t����QU�+�#%��+�a#a愠��37��g��~�6��D
Fx�baL��o<3����k�#������bػ<���ܶh��x�)#���ݥ<ns����6U>rׄ_�½�>��SITGNx����D�M�!�R{��A�w_u/o��]hV����y��+I&�$�+��\�*�#��S5�q�߼����v�!�<1}�9�j��%>�0�����E[*�����Ɓid㻮�mIh/���w\K
����מ���W�̎F�à���-�O_A������4��ɈT�GD�_ë!ҍ�Ps¨��9�h;3>z����;��MWڟ������r�;�
��0��=��2�ʁC��j��L��W��S$��Q�C7�'����N���O��ۍ��ٱk1�.���fXS�A�c�1�H�yG�1#U���z!Yu.�:y0@Dx�N��U�Ε
��f�r�^!:@��&<��5<팕�*�9��a����J'�h5�����S��V.��ͼ�3�q�<r��g�B�3e�"�LpDsh��?�3�d$(��\y7�����3V`��{�H'x�|�΃4�<��:/2@��s7'-�&Bv����.!]ƻ���f��   ����n|��Ѝٰ�1��  ���01�y��jA��   $S�'���9�d�D��)��V";���t�D�e��x��!d�J�x/��\�lẍ+_�� ?nހ���3�����Ǐ��B�d⿈G��>��AX 2�IQ�sg5SmxB����(_����  ���8DÓ�;��/�˕���
�h�T��!
:�X=�O^p/<{�7&e�һ?ÿ���\5c����]�沕�>ח��L��Em�N���Sޏq��������5{3���-��MNl&��Ń��D�9C���m�k��N�u
��Q�����9����[~G���%ʊ#���>�v��  kxQ$.ѲF��ʼ�|�G�$��nxT�8k�:Ώ !��7b�:�V:%z�K����c2�o��J\E\    �]4&)1uX3���#���*�.,�-ۄd7�_;��3K�KTٳ8e�3�P#��ظ�!����aLG(���X�4AzC��`Ω���q��
Z���l�?��\U � c�!��9�~�*v�ލ��U5�� �#R�1�8s�7&����%��S�2��y���ݼ��ԑ�䐑4�NU>����� ��;y����n u­bd5g_��-Hl��f6����/�/��w�y�G��7MPU��  �l-�I8�����ʔ:u\��x�W�)�.N��sV�*�cr�P�u�{��+"�Om�����Q��1�̈�G���w�8f���1�"�%s�~�V>~�=�a�%�dH�
y�K���%PuE���J�[���X��׶/��O���b�Q'�4S�n�GL�q���Z���;9gT[�jD�(�B��   �K��@¼.1r/n���p>��S���5`���0_q`
�����9��]��.8q�?��4�h�4;�~ߐ�2"F���� �b�H㒺�2C�P�>�Y����aQ�Eq����:--��c2��\��������S�z]�r��B� 2ؔO��D\j�1!kDq�t�>�����t�R��Ԥ%����O��Q�P��T``��H$�`��o�|�%��;��������κw}��t+�۴��]7����.<CSU\�x�Cנ�@�
�!�e�Ń@8���������kUGAXIH6˴�� �Z�t�����mXE�L2��#��.�%?�Dlj�*�q̊߸�
5'G����"]��4$sbH�+���?x7l��&`6�� ��y��/<bf  1����E�uv�9H`�M ��ʻ�c/9U��s���s1+j'�@Vx�9�x�Y�
�[�Z���ǷOx�e�ع8CB��Iř�����i|�#��joIR�8�[�{���xl�\!!2/�KO�̫����=7�ց$�@����Vsκ�g���h�W#��qM5۲�n_pB�e�1'�d�
B����eB`c�y�{�����$Q$�PjB=�k+������c6��h�P�0u���&�,t�;&!�!B���O��g#���6�'G����.B�I���q
���`
�0�ۀ)L�!�g�M�z���   (�/��8��o�{���K1��]�-O;��^4C���A    zʴ^��u�r��Tt����)�e�*1�K���-�ȣ�Pu   ��!R�Srr��F�RK�Ӏu�y
_ۗH9��Հ�<��\���xݣ7`Ԉ��ޢ�Y$C���g���!x��W���|@��f�������sD�A�(fg�sw�y��X��    �\D�    ��x����������J�;|鮖G}�64&$�R,�t��'��-N����]�۾t�#Y$���ݝ�R�)��P��;:
ܺ��]o�_�>�Wnub\ U+Q���h�-��K�>�O��=e�1��B�@H�x�77��S���Ӊ�kH��5�G�{<�h�o<m=���5<�7���t�W�T���Cc�#�g~�P�hpɨ>{�7lA3�Ҡ$)�E��k����7(f��R��t�r ��_K����h#��q���d}S�d�IR�k��;'�x�"�TfS���){[���"Vg b��"���/9�����=܎��D#��x�    �8����(�dQĦ������)D�>�#�ZB����@��������8�]7���HuFm�3˳NB��AF��y��'�F�/,�;���㔦��D2x�DC����p�G���΅D3�2X�
�S�nX�j�����=��^}7nU1���_|��ܹ���_7foV��N��u�+��;u�wٛ͘#!T'���nfc���)���C�@PȉN㲓�dr�����Yq�_|�J�t�,�4��"��(U:�����m�2��Y˛.Z���XI�PGq�v�������y�Yk��0�q�<�c���99�b�/����K���X� ҕP�)�����0�hNhh������%�8S U�zB�x���ɹcB�^�GY�߈O�ۆ:fJ��`�o\��_�j7��F���{�~���ā#�t"T��
O�o).E��~W������-�4�5XKD�i�'����}�Y�BB,>h9�-q���k�������#!T%�P�9ƚO�j��
�I�t:��Mr�Җ0�>�k`=�2,q�.k���ɑ�;����'������K���?<�p,2J���&\}o�Q�9fu1C�l�,��<%��C������u�L���=(N�>i�����6.Gp�[)�" G�nyR~�D4A�B�i�3�8�(��,��c/�:��6�7졕�ԧ$����=����/�+h���c^���P�Z>\��j�N��^"��}�7�=��tO8q'{�$���%���2͠�>crCK��$��g:����^��K������WD
$���{&�x��ЊA��������}EXΊY�@�E{b�>{[��Y��2%���   �K�=HM瑉���|݌��gD�Fk�fv(x���e�1��9��)��eJ�y<C�)��ct�qC��'n����{�x�&�@�CZ�=sc�X!ݘ��!+bD���eߤe���P�mf�V��ԇ��}P�ugn<e���XfݨbT"�c!�vS<�=���ƂĒzr�r�h4�c�
�]���7����zJ
RD̙���l�/,�M���&�����������Vv"\��W���3�@������a4�����I�q-��(�k�
��?o#?��5E�e����n݃�30��?˯>�6�o8��7B�>�U���)���=��@C)�p�0ihb���~(��d��b����PB�|��
���R3_�᭜0S��΃S���q�dH���    *
�B�����fY�%�s�A㡿�r�y�   �&��B\��{:�.�"� U]E^`��wE����g�N�:�1��\�@|���L3��!����@D�N����E�|�A�2��Th�hI��x/��t�
F��YM�жί?{'DKd3NX�ݧnE�  
�t���<m˚#��@b�D6KH�3Ds�����A�2���3)�:3�����^p�ٕTU��%0_-����dNj\J�G�ȡ�E�i    8-O�T B�X���G�dG�(M��X�*E��y    ����a�3W+��Ǡ5'�R#g��dj"à�+�
�����-3J����g~Ɇ*�x�'o���@�%V�&L;���������9D;�:�Ԭd��<U$��������6$9��h�����n��a�5"�GA�C��x&����D`J
�TU$���xΖ^�CD�ެ������
���-L�:Bd�o~eW�dB�D�)�n'��->��m�Gm�#hv��}�2y頠�����������*��&�
*�/LK��L$�fx,�d�&U  ɑh��?�!�mU��D�2Y+�h�X7��m����AQSϬ�m#��x7�bىڒ���qd����H�!I�*x�H�(�Y��GlZ=䞉!Q������O�'�O1��9c���GlFs���7&�\1˨df�����o�0]��*�ɕ��(����<-�Kɗi��)j
��)�½�_��>�0��\:*p'yd"Ί����N�M��%���y���k�*vt�����Ε�z��50i�2�P#�H�� �����^u>��k�G��|b�<O=a�&�a/wp�zᚗn��Ytc`ZL:���Ck!�X��ȱ�%�Tl����@���H� $�8UR�V\�{���R��p�'��l5!
[����yܙ+H�
M��%�#�Lq�Af���n�{U�V�up��=�6�V�hh,�B����kw'�߻��놜9��cO��Tʵ���$+�i���<��'�D^|�:�g�8k5�X��A�7}�Nn<7훰e`<�?�����
��~L�N��/~i;Il��k�#����$��8A�\��A��H^p�L�J3][c�L&䪁d����;��j�`"�%e�PHc:Q)|��ܼ� T
���>��sK��g7��*s:g��w��˗�����y�<��k���F^|�f^qn$�"/?��u5�PW��>w�Z$�dU�S��.��c�a@Nc�+>}����ȋ��H ـ� ��%��!O���(Uo�*�4e%j��)��ZV���[v��;c�Ӏ:��K�b�D����yP��J��i[x�3�*�jq�J2f���ۗl����
���ZSd"��R1����=���y��>q
��!Y���NQ):H���3V��?��ϖ�Qa��
�&��|�&��YY�I1!S&�R�f�XH<bs��/>� 5����  $�9���  ���MD
^Z5��杏����q�gIMtǒ�����O�oֽ��htB[�Ơ�l\�98�/-RĵÒL�F1�NY]�֋W�Sע>��!��v���l�흀��
BlI��͈�?v6����Q<'>q���?��\�sK��85Y@
K�����y�FF��tEv/�N�=��3��{�ߌ6
x^��OC�h��3/^�CN�����UɆScfTλ?����m��b⻷D��u3];K��FN-�u$�ga���@O��äc�My�kx��5M��a��b$�BΙ�]N`yY    �ќ��+vq�=��$��i�C�4a�>t��@1={e�]@*��-P�d�[�*�,T�Ԋ��춝|�\�"jeO/m��~����zt���µj���#�j�w�/�YU4�dT#]L\�;�W���L@#Yj2�ّ���:�S����#�@@0��Q�����75h���� A���q'����zm
&��d��bJ6hbE���3i�_��>��΃��Y�:�&}��w�sÒ�vP5y'2���W?����3���ڌ� If ��k���w��d�%�0�I��a��U`�21��Ǚxԉ|���gh�h��$���^b�9w�X���ʻ�J��<�    IDAT�(�d�S��D�h���-� /�BqApv-��s'�(�i&P+&�f�\H�0N�Pq�.��b�P��g�᣷�緾��Js� �^!
��u�̎�Ƅ��� 0���(��K�B����Ǯ���զ8&�s�
��և�YAS) ���*w�M�4@���
5m�0��)?}�jNX��R��'���c�p�����N!  o��3��G���ز�a艖R�/L��`�{�|�h�p�%F!��k��y"���V�r�'�VB���L �()��ƃQ�]t4��xo'�y�n��M�q1$�-�9��WU$    D��+�O��!<�WS�!n���]E�1����/�E�S�*�e'�P�I�,���˙kC�3�F���W��@�L癏n[����/�����"���u4���
uY-/2�g��E�i�.4*�#4u�A<*��x��HN�;�dR�6!�)�ٹqw��yp%3�����9<���J�U%��1�����=c6e����`���'s�
�NC �.�����>T!B�����1*  R&3��)�>�T��!x�Q-�ƒ�$*�����o;�7�4����x��H�;�C0g��A�wS���w�3U��x�LRW8,)����W*&-��2�:�c�(�S0y�`}楸���ad��/�U��(�)�
1$()B�����_��v��l-R;�<SY�Y�Φ�LXX�����G��Ӷ�����|?��
�!��y���07Y���?�z0�=�d��R���g��i\Л�C�#��w�I���Ż�'t�a�H�h�FD����d�LC�2�N���4}�ܨ�� 咡2-ך&B��Mh��\�D�V���)�.Ɇ)��u<�U�8b��a���~
�7`�L�d
K8��O��pU��c��SO�����äg~Ŏ�~$&O\��s�3�J�vB���x�: ���,eo~�W\p6�p/s��RpƏܴ��<�$�L������SWSkW|`ӊ!���پ۸qa��Vt�y�ImZI4�����J�T��Iu9���ST;� /fd`ˊ� �4T��d�.��   '����7,��O��[ge�).�Rf�;O_�/��^��9~�1��.���̺ɱcF2����o
����Eb�f#�\ro�����Jɕ��W���%�L��#B�X�"�Cp�X"��iFEr*�as)7�]R\�w,��E��t�\-'�d}�Z�4#]���ۅ�8)#Ҁ,�{[L�w�T`    !������x��  A-�(@�
�#�����o
����R���.������?��  �@di��R*SmhĕlJX�W���h�|�Ů���~k0Va�2UR�`FK|��*���^��g_�匕������^�Z���6�#Ʃ�/�#�ױ�����#��E���\��4��m����S��L�[���$��:��L�pc��]���o^�wn�W�ؓHnYb�X�$O�>$���2-��#�������Z�@��4���-"J�[�i0���RK��%�L�ŌեIۓO_ͫ���:c5���v%�����͎�F.Ρ����zxc���ZJ����<-��� ��a_���PP�}�
�c��O�#�n�������U�#K%�>����y�1�Q�S%< ��gZ   Ԟ�!m�}��,���#�Mx�'nẃ�.̙|q[Du�w�^^�C7�4Q`��1*ҍٰ~��3��N�H��C��{�O��G�/.�h��!�9T�w8����Wո���;�h����Α@a��m�;�X�����2��pv;r�D0�AK;r�/�by�KCyp�]��KK�>o�����?亂a��~2�9 ���_j(�[�P�rߠK���3|6�@�H�o��~�:~��kYQ����������?_Z�/��/K�R�4�˲�.�p_�;��=|��R׺$ӭO���~�g=S��t= ki��e��p^���!���m��M,�z    t��쇦V�����RQ
ABOd���vה��}�.)���k��q}�~�؟�P�����%M%`Vh�K�mYf��D-���p/�ٺ���Mh��c��F�^!RR8�}��c�Rus��<^P3���K ��Ծ��[��!�=�]���*�\~��A���,3H��:��>��B�r��*�&����s���4��2��V��P�}���}Up�%��`T����@��l�ө�g7.p����LJ�g���s>F#$�������\ͣrmY�|��T��]'|��]�}��}�H�3���p�.K χ��Z��q�$��b�uS�������U����DJF@���B[l�Ŷ#!h��Aݘi"+gB�{�Zc��e�\����-e�3%��Y�L��&2�#G)P�q��??��2R�}����=#�����M�sݒ�1O�5��шM�����~-y֖��>(��-��|��y� ���`��{� k"����ivf�a3`����B�"{cp�Ʋk�z�:
��e���^=q�>���5�)Fv1�;��3����B+����`D2��s>s˄�v�q���z���,�tg�^�k��ǮJ�!��A�CU��]��/�`����Ö�db�Ɗs�y��9�r��t��z�]+`�q��n��[w��HU����*r!DRx�)kx��+8~�ȁ�ჷ-�&�&�XʥG7$�������D�o�A߃�(��+�O    ]�V3_/�u֕�:}Mū���W�lfdԊ֐�gi)������t��J�%�Z���+*s:�2���n]��N^��+����e��M����HU��D�!S�+t��Q�������~0�c�x����$�b��8_����n��n-7ڹ#���K3-��9_�����x�IlXAi�M�d�$�n��Ƕ�+���bn�/j�k\;>ݍyW*̴i���q�xͷ�%�+Y��%f~�k�r�β  �m  1�xX*<�"���x�S�+�w�,w̷|�+;���>%��\/��qb^�T2)`�%-sȰ>³����w��2�����.c�J��M'P�!�U��Ղ�xX2��2������ٚW���:���L���uU��u��gm�]O:�
K��*G�3�=�\᭏9������������ǜ��@�5˦c��s֎�����U���ſ��CqvJ�ii�)Ȓ蘢Q�(ܰ���?��'oi�D�D����e�SyI:�:#UD����v-�}0-��W�P�4Th���:B��c��P  +��MŮ�x���  ����iaS,6��A�@�Ҧ���/�r&��z<0-M�Fzȧ�&�f)^T���L��#��8*FAܔW���C�����G�S\��,U�-(���K�uE
t�B��=�0�0�9�gEE�"�.C�*�)M
�>s%��&��p�@��V�9�ز�U�1�f���j>E}��������
~4��ƃ�����$��{���N���[�����;w�/���7؈����ˡQ�qM�F�%������:�] 2ԁ\�ϡ�,+� T�z�I�7 a�B꟞2�p�������w~{�/?��s���<���Z�E��I�k���BM�N�$���4!Ml9N��1�&.9��PY鏗zs"h2?��$�4���2LfXz�ߦA䌵i��B��>K*�w�^*VK1u���B�������sEc��U�bqD�s��iӀv\�io�UDܺRB��X88�����4�1�e���?�\8K���;��L�����o�ʺ�#_�1C"�y�n痾XT~7 �)�Ϲ�*Ж�\��sn��:�����q����;O�eEoI�x ��˜{G'��CG3-����m��;����{'��_���_�O\���eFd�ܫSoI��c��7B֊��UO���   +gxٷG��b#�Za#+���c8XE��߱� w�_ Ū�
Rv��b��62(9fhg
=���3��6H��!,�
;
V>ZGԥ��0�N˸F�Z~�q'p�5����Į�E$�kKLt5?�����<�����`��%T�����1o���-tH��r�&������uO<��:*���V����q�����G<�QJ�B[$0�CRp>{�>޿mB��$�j�t����8H��/����0 t�xm��i&���̾����q
��J11(޷�"����#�2�"KOK�4�.��eϴH��ް�غ�F[:]�ZaF��PT}�I�#8�5�{��T5�f�J������*�ڈ9R����M�a��9uň��(R��?�r��� ��dS��<�s���ӄ�+���o;
��XAо�:�ޢR�i��V��<=P��g
�?�e)��g�p`~#o�b;z���Nhc�T�+��ͅ�7�� ��B�ض���A�b9ެc��
��|�z^�ue?��Bw�ԃ�K�u�y�KaW�G�"����1M!r�T*�7�앾
u���_=�/����J�:*���I�%�_�}���n��)94�L0�?��y�]Wu�{8�{�d�g?���ĥq�`H����
RE�Pu�E�
1UT�(C+��%��D�B[�FM�SW����ó���{��s��?�>�9�������s��g��^�[���{O
y�|æ����    ���E�y�j���X������)x%2�Rョ�U�<�:�p�����ͦ ���R��M��-�����4��[3���2l���6���L���\&J���I��.q���
���C��"�����&(���n��+��oF�A G�h�pe���%߸�%��0J�R�,3�]E@��i��8��m����}�<zV��s\���Nsr\st4��e�v�DE�%�5<xV������e�ι��o�����s�����1jT�    h4üc��D�x��`�or�"E�k5�����=��*�4�ΐm��AVn;t��7-r�˜d(3FX#��d���H�p�$�9xE��E����hĹш�ʂKɈN���d�R��T�4B���E�m�ҥ�O��n�mo�8nHy0MR[|쾓��b�9:FRX&F��@�苒`�nҩd bH]�Ī����i-b)�y��x�f�H��orA�v���q5�+���u�.�NQ�
F��.P)Q����޳#���2���    sn\s~���+&Ę����������|6�j
}
��:������K�y��
WNN��-�����jʤ��Ji���{8��������̨�kg�&�a
��_;�ʃG�p8XGW#M��׉������n�zϟ5L�<��&���LY�t\�^F9����g�Y�IT�X[)��5u�r�ǚA�K�y�щ2jlR�:�F"Uq�I�9/
-�"�D����1N�s���H&b�c��sK��?z�����mDm')l>Dy_�bI�c����w�%B�e�%�M�('A�QÚ� ŋ�  ޽m�D    n�8�?&x������5h�}gV��   �R�^��a6��+S^'�4L�׉��L�7�b#R�߅���×Q0�:*���;���@4kz�Vy��݁Xt�J)&s��
O��w�3��iK�x�6�r��,Յ�<��)t��� E�R\+?��ّ�ֻ���..9FE���iӠ��&���X�'J~�zYh>�31���y��)]�=�āӲ�S�b �D�\ ��ڰJJ�I*�z�f�rh��������QrG��o,����X�`�h���G�ˡ��4&�����Cf�)����Kr�RAzM…�yeV�\D��,,���bx7n�b@b�*U&�4��Չ�q��\��N
�Un�#�p�X���r﷎�����CӧZʓ+�x}����=�b��%>p�L���mh>��L�8�ѩ�R��=Y&�
�CW�T�dw�߅ǝ��sr�r#����V��~�-W��ы��w`HVQ��� ���H��ĿoUAL����;�<�wո.@41ʠ�BE�wQG�w�.B��O�ܼ��Z��צURE[% �Д)�M�ţI)b�o���_N>|�I�8/?a�a�5evTlh��_q�f&�?+ƭc�;'��6�wWD�)PQa�%7�~�{6�xƜ�@��
��M�ో�~�Lm)�`��W�G�cϡ+φ����r��Ҙ�D�ؓq1�h\��Ҧ�/�E4NI�@:��ݛ�gɬgL��&�N���}F[��S&я.���%�����a*��D���0�ab�[��&��i�2�J%1Jɖ�s���kf���a��=±��T�6bR$�ء#D%x�s�v�T ���sLM.��ӏ�
�n��}���֔s�S��BF-?��
���R�]�H�%:T�DmH:3��ꄎ>��aPG6n��/��v�:y�B�[�K����)J!CPƂœ��[� `���y�ḏ)�,M����Z��
vm��n����#F��O��K�<MN��:���?F�b���%�9-��r���"�����g���1�ҋv���/�*RY���#N�w��\�"��J'B��GF+B�Ƨ)b��J$md�O���E����|��e@&�I��L���|q��W�����t#;��|��C���
k4)�*�L�
P�1%>�+�n������O�gw搻��*�t����"�jDT�#{>kD;3���
���<�oo��t�(b   Y�ڴF+�*���e'>p����  �OBUsR�n��eY��)�uCp�^%�{�K����
�,ض֣s����/���L�Acr�=��2�c��>x�/�{�X�n:xE�>)x ыVb������Go��Ι��M�);f47lY�ݧŵ �>�2
|G,F�5<!�9���;'��QA��p�9�e�M���6��ʳ�~U�ϼj����-�%�AiO�R�m�Z�� ~5k����E�o*��\���=���l(���4#�[֮H㆙  ͛���_����4手�R���hh`htZ�K5b׺�̓�F!:I�[o{�<��tA�q�q���Hx ��jU�J�"�|    PX��
���|P��Ԙ�?v�_�f=Q�����<lM�u*���u�"�H&���(s�x�kL�(tO+��x^���m���]V�"����j�OMY�*OI�%1?�Q���|���l_"xMB��x/�|���<m�4�M{g�9S��< ���dɞu��O��.I^��_�c�Fŀ��Z�;>���P��n8�7˗���
�   .kz��)�7O�ڽ�-�JE�0:��*���HŐQ���;5��{1��#>(��:bt$��pѶ���F�3^l��N�w?:�W���T�� u���%����PG1�J������Y�T��J�ƈ�!xvLJ;��s[X;��xM����8�f4����BM9�I�5����.��2�)(9;t톋1��ɩ�m�$#UJaZ�$�vU��Ys���E�G��C��3R�ݹJ�Đ#�|w
<=�|��)��?M�J������D�pe��)U�%����������v݁��6��/ݱ��,F������
F'��'�����/���$���S�Y�C"�ؽ}Q���Zj�f%p��3����O�s^W�B�\��F� 
���0�:O��   WVy߁s<tZV_��/�HhkqL�bU��A��zu�Qc�����Q����UC�˓��{���*�`F����    ��B^U�]���������l�#�#th���G���ҫ�N���%�
Jk�=i{j��"6I�bǺB{yǨ<�V����}�a|AP
����i��#cܮj*4(S���X��o��ֈ<��˒�g����ynh�qo��@
*6h�^���1�����6�{*3��D���P�*��m��L%��BeD����(q��h(�9��
II}Q� JG�J��J��X�&T&���PӨ��*^��?�㻇/��ĎXR�@�z#��C��������cK*K�fD(,:9bK�7��4>MB���0ml鏨%�)�D��4�S&O�֊�=���EF-C)֨�֚��]q���cj�\H��Z|6jL*Fw.�V[g���e�h��
R�����(*���:>zcF�X�l��
���IDAT���
�'�W��cQ�Q��.���M<5�kmun?V2'.���=�2|��3(��"$@/9�AcQ�9�]�
[-���m\��\�����d��>e�<s�W���}�G��Umb�j����3�{#�[a��&RK���:��[Q�+C�Yy�L�K�؛�����������[$��6��2!h�Z��+CI���k�F(�:���J�d
J���Q��ܯ�J[��n��H�Z��(��ZH
�   Fw�->D�PR3!���LJ�9hSt>�V�(  ��5r}���z����]���!c���v�.��)D{!i��2Rn'�`��^�W���{;�&4���s<)z�|�f�����l���PP(��%����|TJ��&��].��!��V<c%��H��U��
1�`JK������ǆ�"��.�݂�خj�NY^�N����kb2kZU��G����ۿi�_�3`��x`��?�k�m5a�D(d���\Ǖ��#�_;P9��v�641�����5���m{u�U4uИ /�b�g��2�W   4߃�ȗ�9�X�׉JgB���OB��4k��˳�/���:��)�E7�{�1�f���>AO)��I�9��1�X%0R�~4]���R��/j�s���>�J�s��-�N��o��Tt���螼��B��nbK�M �_�\�����֬Cw�}ΞY��x�f�(Q��A�UhHVv(�Ȝ���m�#{㛼K4�7ZQ  "�\�F�ky_Vf�z�0e�YN������ %%"�O���E��A�^���gU�6!t�h�JGt#t�g1�0ZX��N �(Ť6̶2�HE�P�s��4ӌPJ���佧6ň2Ch����Zà�NG�1=T,��_��'jӑ�uΪ�O����0������jS����L)�
'��n�)8Qlۀ4]�|��-ڪQ�c���0��w㉓C�s�U�����6a(�[OE�4R�Mj*Ն���w=2|��x�]'���{��ʫy٦��,����OXm�
�EG��/%�~���PkDt3TIEND�B`�
```

I have tried using `Base64Decoder().convert(response)` and `Base64.Decode()` but both these methods are giving `FormatException` at first character.

If I am hitting the same api in the postman it is automatically rendering the image in its console.

let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: what are 8 first bytes in hex? is it `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A` or something similar?

Comment: so do you want me to convert it into hex?

Comment: yes call `int.toRadixString` on first 8 bytes

Comment: on response data of the api?

Comment: can you help me what type of data it is.

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/bodyBytes.html?

Comment: I think I got something now, something like [137 ....] as list of int, let me check if I render this as image.

Comment: convert it to hex, use [toRadixString](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/toRadixString.html) method for first 8 items in the list

Comment: documents says, The radix argument must be an integer in the range 2 to 36.

but I am getting 134 the first element of the list.

Comment: `final data = [137, 40, 211, 32, 111, 234, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0];
final hex = data.take(8).map((i) => i.toRadixString(16)).join(',');
print(hex);`

Comment: 89,50,4e,47,d,a,1a,a

Comment: so it is a valid png image - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures and type `ctrl-F` `‰PNG` - you can directly pass it to [Image.memory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html) constructor

Comment: ok let me try. thanks

Comment: @pskink it is working but it is kinda stopping the UI, the length of the response list is  17315.

Comment: is there any other way to render this?

Comment: i dont see any reason why 17kB response would stop the UI

Comment: me neither.  let me check then there should be some other issue. can dio be reason?

Comment: Thank you @pskink, the only issue was with dioPrettyLogger, since it was printing all the 17k elements to the console, it was the reason that is stopping the UI.

Comment: good to know ;-)